# what does it mean by 'you are onto a winner'?

Tags: american-english, british-english

Somebody explains a situation and told me that in that situation 'you are onto a winner'.

what does it mean by 'you are onto a winner'?

Comment: What research have you done to try to answer this yourself?

Comment: **Ask them**. They knew exactly what they meant, and you were already talking to them. But you patiently waited for them to go away, to then ask a bunch of random strangers off the Internet instead. That makes no sense at all. You have all the context and the author available for comment, and still don't know what they meant — but then you give random strangers *no context at all,* nor any chance to talk to the author, and tell them to go do better than you did. What is the point of this exercise? Why are you doing that? Not cool. Not cool at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"You are onto" means you're "on the track of", or that you're pursuing the appropriate path towards something--in this case, towards success. "A winner" is an idea, topic, or proposal that is likely to be successful.

In short, it means "You have a good idea" or "This is a good situation".